# Content change without effect header and footer?

Tags: android, gallery, android-tabhost

Below is my UI

[image]

What I need is when the user clicks on any button in the footer menu(gallery), the content(activity) area will change depend on the menu. but it wont effect header and footer area.

Different content has its own layout and function and controlled by it own activity class. How can I do like this? Is TabHosh can do it? Or have other solution?

Sorry for my bad english. Hope u guys understand what I'm talking about.
Thanks.

Comment: YOu need to use **Gallery** for that.

Comment: Hi krishna, I'm try before.. but unfortunately when i click the menu(gallery), the header and footer was change together.. what i need is only the content area changing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

- https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Screenshot:

[image]